# htaccess redirect domain to https, subdomain to https and non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I’m looking to do this:

Force the https for my main domain.

http to https://www.
http://www to https://www.

But not for subdomains

http://subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com

Can some one help me i can't find this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use that in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# redirect to https www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

[EDIT]

```
RewriteEngine on 

# redirect no-www to www only main domain, not with subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect http to https all domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if i change below wil the subdomains redirect https
# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

to

# redirect to https subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: ok, got it. I have updated my answer. you can use **EDIT** section

Comment: What if we need to remove `index.php` along with this from url?

Comment: That was a serious help